# where should I ask a question about using Microsoft Word?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've got a problem using Microsoft Word - surely there's a Stack Exchange site for that, isn't there?

Comment: [su] is probably your best bet on desktop-esque support.

Comment: For future reference, you can get the list of all the Stack Exchange sites here: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com). From the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking

*(emphasis mine)*

You may find your question has already been answered in https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word.